# SQL Запрос update не работает

Tags: php, mysql, sql, update

Не пойму что делаю не так, поправьте пожалуйста:

Главный файл

```
<? $History = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT history.id, history.text, history.status, users.name FROM history INNER JOIN users ON history.uid = users.id ORDER BY history.id"); ?>
    <tbody>
      <?php while ($Query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($History)) echo '
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">'.$Query['id'].'</th>
        <td>'.$Query['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$Query['text'].'</td>
        <td>
          <form method="POST" action="/query">
            <select class="custom-select" size="1" name="status">
                '.str_replace('>'.services_status($Query['status']), 'selected>'.services_status($Query['status']), '
                <option value="0">Заказано</option>
                <option value="1">Активно</option>
                <option value="2">Отказано</option>
                ').'
            </select>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Изменить">
          </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
      ';
      ?>
    </tbody>
```

UPTADE файл

```
<?
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `history` SET `status` = $_POST[status] WHERE `id` = $_POST[id]");
}?>
```

Если изменить код на тот что внизу, то работает, НО будет изменять ВСЕ данные таблицы.

```
    <?
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `history` SET `status` = $_POST[status]");
}?>
```

Comment: 1. Как вы определили, что запрос "не работает"? 2. В таблице `history` есть поле `id`? 3. Какое значение находится в `$_POST[id]`?

Comment: В таблице `history` есть поле `id`, в `$_POST[id]` по сути значение текущей услуги

Comment: `по сути значение текущей услуги` - по сути или точно?))) а если просто номер поставить в `WHERE \`id\` = 1` например то что будет? вместо 1 - существующий номер

Comment: @Puvvl чему равно это значение? Вы его проверяли?

Comment: собссн в вашей форме нет элемента с именем `id`

Comment: Если поставить `WHERE id = 14` то изменит статус 14-той услуги, почему тогда не работает `$_POST[id]`?

Comment: @Puvvl см. выше ↑

Comment: Подскажите что нужно дописать, пожалуйста))

Comment: @Puvvl что-то наподобие `<input type="hidden" name='id' value="' . $Query['id'] . '" />` в коде формы.

Comment: Спасибо всем, получилось с `<input type="hidden" name='id' value="' . $Query['id'] . '" />`

Comment: @Puvvl на здоровье. Раз всё получилось, то либо можно удалить вопрос, либо я могу это разместить в качестве ответа, если вы готовы его принять.

Comment: в $_POST скобках название элемента обязательно должно помещаться в кавычки: например вместо $_POST[status] - $_POST['status']

Answer (score 0):

Так как в форме нет элемента с `name="id"`, то в `$_POST[id]`, по факту, нет никакого `id`. Чтобы он отправлялся при отправке формы, можно добавить в код формы скрытый `<input>` с соответствующим `name`:

```
<input type="hidden" name='id' value="' . $Query['id'] . '" />
```